# Jump to the latest blank lattern on vim using a shortcut

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I have currently started to use vim and been trying for a while to *get used to it's rules and be as efficient as possible*. But due to my lack of knowldege I have encountered a problem which really seems to slow me done. I've noticed that if **I use my arrow keys it would get me to the second last character of the line** and it would be nice **if I cloud use a shortcut to get to the very end of the line**. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/) or the integrated help system (typing `:help` in vim) and go to the `motion` section.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html

In `normal mode` you can press:

- `$` to go to the end of the line
- `A` to go to the end of the line and start in `insert mode`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply press the `End` key to reach the end of the line. Additionally, holding down the `Ctrl` key while pressing left or right keys will jump to the start/end of the next word.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
Use `$` to get to the end of the line. Check out the vim cheat sheet here: https://vim.rtorr.com/

Comment: Thank you for your comment man but both answers jump me to the last lattern of the sentence not after that,so it doesnt allow me to actually continue the sentence but thank you for your comment anyways man <3  @Ram